# How can my plugin render a generic Matrix block in the Control Panel?

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, control-panel

Here's a sample of a matrix block:
[image]

I would like to have my own fields inside the block and retain the basic functionalities like Collapse, Disable, etc. Basically, just use the Matrix block UI without using the Matrix field.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to pull this off by referencing **MatrixInput.js** and **/_components/fieldtypes/Matrix/input.html**.

[image]